# Kronecker-factored least-squares?

Tags: linear-solver, linear-system

Suppose $a_i,b_i$ are $d\times 1$ matrices, $y_i$ is scalar, and I need to find least-squares solution $w$ of the following system of $n$ equations:

$$y_i=(a_i^T\otimes b_i^T)w$$

Is there a specialized approach for this system?
Converting to normal equations and applying Cholesky to solve for $w$ takes takes $O(d^6)$ operations. This is a quite a bit expensive than verifying the solution at $O(d^2)$ operations. I was hoping for an approach that scales as $O(d^4)$ or $O(d^3)$. For my problem, $d\le n<d^2$

Comment: Isn’t the Kronecker product 1xd^2 in this setting? How is w size dx1?

Comment: [Very similar recent question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36393/symmetric-matrix-which-satisfies-conditions-of-the-form-v-it-x-v-i-0#comment71038_36393), which is basically the symmetric version of your problem. It did not get a positive answer, so it looks like this one is going to be similar.

Comment: Is $n$ the number of equations? The system is underdetermined then; you can't solve it with Cholesky.

Comment: @JesseChan corrected

Comment: Do the $n$ vectors $b_i$ span your $n$-dimensional space?

Comment: yes, and it can be assumed that the solution exists